# required field if other field doesn't have specific value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a field project which is required if `account_name` field doesn't have the value '0'. I want to validate this scenario in laravel

```
eg if account_name = '0'  -project_name field is not required 
   if account_name = '1'    - project_name field is required 


 $this->validate($request,[
     'project_name'=>'required_without:account_name,0',
    ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `required_unless`! Then the name will be required unless account_name equals 0.

```
 $this->validate($request,[
     'project_name'=>'required_unless:account_name,0',
    ]);
```